# Pass Variables As Reference AS3

Tags: function, variables, actionscript-3, reference

I have a function which has arguments that will modify multiple variables that are global.  And I want the arguments to be reference arguments, so they can modify multiple global variables with the same lines of code that are modifying the arguments.

example(psuedocode):

```
function random(a:number, b:number, c:number):void{
a = RNG(20);
b = RNG(25);
c = RNG(30);
}
```

there will be two different variables passed in through a, b and c, these are global, but a, b and c are not.  The goal is to not have to have identical lines of code for both separate sets of variables to set the RNG numbers.

Edit:  So I suppose more explanation is in order I will probably just try to research making a wrapper or other object to add all the variables to, but I just didn't know what type of object to make and how to make it.  I admit I was just being a little bit lazy in a little bit too complex creative way.

I have two sets of global variables that I want to pass into this function and set them equal to the same range of RNG as the corresponding ones in each set.  The way I'm trying to do this without repeating "a = RNG(20);" twice for each one is by passing the global variables into the function as arguments, but the arguments are the variables that are having the RNG set to them.  The only way this can work is if the variables are passed to the function as reference so that setting the RNG to the arguments will change the global variables.

Comment: There are two types of data in AS3: plain data (**Boolean**, **String**, **Number**, **int**, **uint** — always passed as values) and objects (**Object**, **Array** and literally everything else — always passed as a pointer/reference rather than through copy/clone). There's no trick, like in C/C++ there is, to pass some plain variable as a pointer to let a method modify the original and only value. That said, you need either to pass variables indirectly (like in pairs container:var.name) or devise a custom wrapper class to cross the border between plain and object data.

Comment: Ok, I was afraid this might be the answer.  I will have to do some research as to the syntax for creating an object with custom variables.  Technically I suppose with adding more code this could make it easier in the long run, but I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some simple way to do it like adding an & or some symbol to the arguments.  Go ahead and answer and i will accept it.

Comment: Do you have a better example for pseudo? Extend it to show the global vars too, so we can see how they fit into your description. Your example code simply edits the function's current input parameters of `number` type called `a`, `b` and `c`. How does a different "global" declared `var a` get involved here? Are you wanting an `a && a = RNG` type of solution (where left `a` is global and right-side `a` is the function parameter)?

Comment: PS: Try chaining vars with `=` to give multiple vars the same value. _Example:_ `var glob_A :int = 5;` and `var someOther :int =10;` then call your function with `random( someOther);` means `someOther` is now the `a` in your function. To use same function to also update the global `glob_A` you simply set inside function as `a = glob_A = RNG( );`  so now function param `a` has same value as `glob_A` which itself has value of `RNG` function. Thus using 1 line to update multiple vars, if that's your expected result.  PPS: If you got global var `a` then change your param name _eg:_ to `input_a`

Comment: The global variables are the ones being passed into the function because I wanted to pass different types of global variables into the same function but have each variable retain the same value as was added to the arguments which correspond to the global variables that were passed into the function.  I will try to update the question with a more specific explanation now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of data in AS3:

1. Plain data: **Boolean**, **String**, **Number**, **int**, **uint** — always passed as values.
2. Objects: **Object**, **Array** and literally everything else — always passed as a pointer/reference rather than through copy/clone.

There's no trick, like in C/C++ there is, to pass some plain variable as a pointer to let a method modify the original and only value.

That said, there are two ways around.

**Solution №1**: you can pass variables indirectly, in pairs like container → variable name.

```
function doIt(A:Object, a:String):void
{
    A[a] = RNG(20);
}
```

**Solution №2**: devise a custom wrapper class to cross the border between plain and object data.

Implementation:

```
package
{
    public class Oint
    {
        public var data:int;

        // Class constructor.
        public function Oint(value:int = 0)
        {
            data = value;
        }

        // There's always nice to have a interface methods,
        // rather than member or getter/setter, because
        // you can actually link to read/write methods.
        public function read():int
        {
            return data;
        }

        public function write(value:int):void
        {
            data = value;
        }

        // With this you can use Oint variables in math expressions.
        public function valueOf():Object
        {
            return data;
        }

        // With this you can trace Oint variables and see their values.
        public function toString():String
        {
            return data.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
function random(a:Oint, b:Oint, c:Oint):void
{
    a.data = RNG(20);
    b.data = RNG(25);
    c.data = RNG(30);
}
```

Comment: Ok so one thing I'm realizing is that arrays count as a reference object is that correct?  I forgot that all the rng values probably can be stored in arrays.  So, I don't have to make some kind of other random object to hold all the variables' values.  Returning the specific variables will not be an option since I have about 5 variables that I want to change.  Do you have a link to the syntax for making a custom object in AS3 otherwise I can look it up, but I think maybe just passing an array into the function would work okay for my purposes.

Comment: @Jyreeil Yes, **Array** is an object too, you can pass a reference to it with a list of its element indices, like **function random(A:Array, a:int, b:int, c:int):void**

Comment: Thanks for the help Organis.  I got my program working the way I wanted it to, just had to shuffle some things around.

Comment: @Jyreeil Glad to hear it : )